# Old Domain to New Domain redircetion using Nginx but not working getting 404

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am attempting to redirect traffic from an old API site that was originally running on localhost:5000. I had set up a reverse proxy at api.example.com, but now the SSL certificate for api.example.com has expired. We're not using *.example.com anymore; instead, we're using *.example2.com, which already has a valid SSL certificate. There are also other sites running on this domain.

My goal is to redirect traffic from api.example.com to api.example2.com. However, despite configuring the nginx server block, I'm encountering a 404 error. When I check with curl-I, it shows a 301 permanently moved response

Below is the nginx configuration for the site:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api.example.com;

    # Redirect to api.example2.com
    return 301 https://api.example2.com$request_uri;
}
```

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.example.com;
  ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/example2.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example2.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

I need assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

- Update SSL Certificate:

Make sure that the SSL certificate (example2.com.crt) and the corresponding key (example2.key) match the new domain (api.example2.com). If you've changed the domain, using the old certificate for the new domain could result in SSL errors.

- Correct Server Name:

Update the server_name in the second server block to reflect the new domain:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.example2.com;  # Update to the new domain
    ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/example2.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example2.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    # ... (rest of the configuration remains the same)
}
```

- Check DNS Configuration:

Ensure that the DNS records for api.example2.com are correctly pointing to the server where Nginx is running. Also, allow some time for DNS changes to propagate.

- Restart Nginx:

After making changes to the Nginx configuration, restart Nginx to apply the changes:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

- Clear Browser Cache:

Sometimes, browsers cache redirects. Clear your browser cache or try accessing the site in an incognito/private browsing window to avoid cached redirects.

- Test with Curl:

Use curl to test the redirection and check the headers:

```
curl -I https://api.example.com
```

Ensure that you get a 301 response with the correct new location, [sigma juego](https://sigmaxdownload.com/sigma-juego-descargar-sigma-apk/).

By addressing these points, you should be able to resolve the 404 error and successfully redirect traffic from api.example.com to api.example2.com. If the issue persists, carefully review the Nginx error logs (/var/log/nginx/error.log) for any specific error messages that might provide additional insights into the problem.

Comment: Hey James,

I've made sure to update the server name in the second server block with port 443, and the SSL path is correct and valid. However, I'm encountering an error when I try curl -I using HTTPS. Additionally, when attempting to access curl at http  ://api.example.com, I receive a '301 Moved Permanently' response.

Could you assist me with resolving this issue? Thanks in advance for your help